# Disk usage of all the files in a directory

Tags: linux, find, disk-usage

I am trying to get the disk usage of all the files present in a particular directory using the following commands and I am getting different answers for both. Could anyone explain why?

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.*' -exec du -csh {} + | grep total$
83M total

find ./ -type f -exec du -csh {} + | grep total$
101M total
38M  total
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have files that don't match `*.*`.

Try

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.*'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you also explain why there are two values in the second case ?

Comment: @Stuti It should be clear from running your pipeline without the final `grep` part.

Comment: There are two result lines because there are too many names for one invocation of `du`, it is split in two.